# Disable video.js spinner AND keep default skin

Tags: video.js

I was trying to disable the loading spinner, as it hangs on some browsers.

I found an existing solution, which definitely works. This line:

data-setup="{"children": {"loadingSpinner": false}}"

Problem is this code addition changes the skin of my player.

1. Spinner disabled, new skin: http://thinkmad.com/s/projects/little-racer-dancing/
2. Old skin:http://thinkmad.com/s/projects/parachute-youth-count-to-ten/

Both still have:

class="video-js vjs-default-skin"

Anyone know how to fix this so all my skins are consistent?

Alex

Answer (score 1):

When I use single quotes instead of double quotes, the progress spinner returns and the original problem persists:

http://thinkmad.com/s/projects/little-racer-dancing/

I'll also mention this is a video that is 720p but on the page I've resized it to 640x360. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

In your video tag you have `data-setup="{"children": {"loadingSpinner": false}}"` change this to use single quotes `'` around your `data-setup` attribute like so

```
data-setup='{"children": {"loadingSpinner": false}}'
```

your code is closing the attribute with just `{`